# iOS - local notification - custom design to show

Tags: ios, jailbreak

[image]

How can I show custom design (Shown Image) in local notification?

Comment: You can't unless you jailbreak. Is that an option?

Comment: means? if i have jailbreak phone then it is possible otherwise not? am i right?

Comment: That is correct, Pratik.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS take a look at UILocalNotification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil) return;

localNotif.fireDate = someDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody = @"This is a custom message."
localNotif.alertAction = @"View Details";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Other wise in Jailbreak there could be option.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: how can customization in jailbreak phone?

Comment: Then select your Tag to jailbreak, people with jailbreak experience will help you out. :)